# HeapDumpPath: %p not working

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am trying to assign a custom `HeapDumpPath` when running my java app. The new path is applied, but `%p` placeholder is not replaced by a real value (process ID is expected here).

Use of `%p` is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html) - look for `-XX:HeapDumpPath=./java_pid%p.hprof`

I wrote this simple app to test the behavior:

```
public class MainOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        String last = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            last = last + last;
            strings.add(last);
            System.out.println(strings.size());
        }
    }
}
```

Running it like this on standard Oracle Java 8 installation (on Linux):

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle$ ./bin/java \
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
    -XX:HeapDumpPath=./java_pid%p.hprof \
    -classpath jre/lib/rt.jar:/path/to/project/target/classes \
    package.name.MainOverflow
```

But the result is:

> ...
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>
> Dumping heap to ./java_pid%p.hprof ...

Something like ./java_pid**2504**.hprof was expected. So, the question is: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it create files with PID in the name, if you ,ale the dump path a directory?

Comment: Yes, it does: `Dumping heap to ./java_pid16739.hprof`.

Comment: great! so can you just run with that, or do you require/want a custom heap dump filename with the pid embedded in it?

Comment: I really need a custom heap dump filename, either with PID or some random value in it. I just need to make sure the filename is unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always set heap dump path to point at a directory and add commands in `OnOutOfMemoryError` option:

```
-XX:HeapDumpPath="heapdumps/"
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="..."
```

According to [JVM troubleshooting guide by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html) you can use `%p` in `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError` option.

Therfore I would try something like this (assumes custom location and default filename of the heap dump):

```
 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="mv heapdumps/java_pid%p.hprof heapdumps/myenv_heapdump_%p.hprof"
```

Comment: Double quotes make no difference. But the `OnError` option is a good idea. In my case I had to use `OnOutOfMemoryError`, the whole code goes: `-XX:HeapDumpPath="./heapdumps/" -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="mv ./heapdumps/java_pid%p.hprof ./heapdumps/myenv_heapdump_%p.hprof"`

Answer (score 1):

The setting requires the path only. Do not append the expected file name. This is generated automatically by the VM.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html

Comment: I know it supports both folder and file mode. I need to use the file mode, so I wanted to use the PID to differentiate individual dumps. The PID placeholder does not seem to work, though.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer for Java 8. [tested on 17-May-2021]

You only need to give directory name in `-XX:HeapDumpPath` option.

So if your directory is : C:/work/myCustomFolder, simply give : -`XX:HeapDumpPath="C:/work/mycustomFolder"`. a file will be created with the name : "java_pid1234.hprof" in this folder. (1234 is just an example for pid.)